# Y a-t-il une différence de prononciation entre [disemine] et [dissemine] (disséminer/dissémination) ?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique

Dans un [texte](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/politique-canadienne/201902/13/01-5214679-un-conseiller-de-maxime-bernier-defend-ses-ecrits-polemiques.php) où on peut lire les propos navrants d'un libertarien faisant l'apologie du révisionnisme néo-fasciste on peut aussi lire d'autres propos du même acabit au sujet de la « [dissémination](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diss%C3%A9mination) des armes [à feu] ». En vérifiant si malgré lui il la comparaît à la *dissémination des germes d'une maladie* je remarque une note pour la prononciation ([diseminasjɔ ̃]) où l'on indique que pour le verbe [*disséminer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diss%C3%A9miner) ([disemine]) on aurait aussi la « possibilité de prononcer [ss] double » (TLFi) et on donne comme référence [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/diss%C3%A9miner), entre autres, lequel indique (di-ssé-mi-né)... Je ne suis pas capable d'imaginer cette différence de prononciation.

---

- Y a-t-il une différence entre la prononciation [disemine] et
  [dissemine] (ou avec *dissémination*) et peut-on expliquer en quoi
  elle consiste ; est-ce un simple « allongement » (comme le « son que
  fait le serpent ») ; le cas échéant dispose-t-on toujours de ce choix
  de prononciation aujourd'hui ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux prononciations s'entendent mais la plus courante est [disemine].

L'autre est plus soignée.

On prononce alors le début du mot comme s'il commençais par *dix*:

> dix - séminé [dissemine]

Le double *s* est perçu comme un *s* allongé, mais la différence tient surtout à la première syllabe qui inclut alors un *s*.

On peut faire un parallèle entre les prononciations respectives de

> - La dent, ses dents [ladɑ̃], [sedɑ̃]

et

> - Là-dedans, c'est dedans (avec *e* muet : *là d'dans*, *c'est d'dans*) [laddɑ̃], [seddɑ̃]

Comment: @Jardindefrostedflakes C'est pour donner un autre exemple de consonne doublée [la**d**ɑ̃] vs [la**dd**ɑ̃], pareil pour *ses dents* comparé à *c'est dedans*. Il faut que le `e` de `dedans` soit muet pour que ça ait un sens.

Comment: Ah ok merci je vois là. Peut-être éventuellement ajouter à la réponse les trucs entre crochets, je pense que mon attention était captée par l'absence de grave sur le _a_ et l'orthographe différente des deux mots...